# The name 'ModelState' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

If we look at the manual here it states that we should use same old `ModelState.IsValid` or `TryValidateModel()` yet when I create a project, restore it I don't have access to it.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the manual: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation.html

> The name 'ModelState' does not exist in the current context

```
using Api.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/authorization")]
    public class AuthorizationController
    {
        [Route("login"), HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Authorize(UserViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState) // ModelState does not exist.
            {
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your controller needs to inherit from ApiController (or Controller). What you have there isn't really a controller!

Answer (score 0):

I received this error from within the view .cshtml file when trying to do this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid){ ... }
```

To fix, I needed to reference the `ViewContext`, like this:

```
if (!ViewContext.ModelState.IsValid){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AuthorizationController : ControllerBase { ... }
```

You forgot the ": ControllerBase". Try this!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).